# Eureka Discovery client is not register under API-GATEWAY\host.docker.internal

Tags: spring-boot, docker, microservices

I have used the Eureka discovery server for setting up the microservices.

Initially, DiscoveryClient was registered under DiscoveryClient_API-GATEWAY/host.docker.internal:api-gateway. Now it has changed to the machine name DiscoveryClient_API-GATEWAY/SL-GGnanaseelan.mshome.net:api-gateway, and it's throwing the following error.

Could you please help with this?

```html
2024-03-28T16:24:19.884+05:30  INFO 20080 --- [api-gateway] [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Discovery Client initialized at timestamp 1711623259882 with initial instances count: 0
2024-03-28T16:24:19.886+05:30  INFO 20080 --- [api-gateway] [           main] o.s.c.n.e.s.EurekaServiceRegistry        : Registering application API-GATEWAY with eureka with status UP
2024-03-28T16:24:19.887+05:30  INFO 20080 --- [api-gateway] [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Saw local status change event StatusChangeEvent [timestamp=1711623259887, current=UP, previous=STARTING]
2024-03-28T16:24:19.889+05:30  INFO 20080 --- [api-gateway] [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_API-GATEWAY/SL-GGnanaseelan.mshome.net:api-gateway: registering service...
2024-03-28T16:24:19.970+05:30  INFO 20080 --- [api-gateway] [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_API-GATEWAY/SL-GGnanaseelan.mshome.net:api-gateway - registration status: 204
```

```html
java.net.UnknownHostException: Failed to resolve 'SL-GGnanaseelan.mshome.net' [A(1)] after 2 queries 
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.finishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:1125) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
```

Now
[image]

eailer
[image]